# can my 2 GB sd card be used as ram like in windows 7?

Tags: performance, ram

I'm trying to increase the ram on my old computer with a 2 GB sd card. You can configure Windows to use an SD card like RAM and I'm wondering if Ubuntu has that same ability.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct you need to format it as a swap partition:

1. Plug in the SD card.
2. If Ubuntu automounts the device, unmount the device.
3. Use `sudo mkswap /dev/sda1` (assuming /dev/sda1 is you SD card)
4. Do `sudo swapon -p 32767 /dev/sda1` (again assuming /dev/sda1 is you SD card)

and that should do the job

You can check this by typing `cat /proc/swaps` into a terminal and you should see you device listed (/dev/sda1)

Comment: How effective is that likely to be in increasing performance? Your run-of-the-mill SD card isn't all that fast.

Comment: I've done this myself and unless you have a fast SD card or really low ram you are unlikely to see any increase in performance. ZRAM, on the other hand, really seemed to help out my older play-around laptop with 1.5GiB RAM when running lots of Chrome windows.